# how compare 2 json array and based on match construct 3rd json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a situation where i have to compare 2 `json arrays` if their `name` matches with each other than

i have to `construct` the third `json array`.

**example:**  consider `1st json array`  `[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646"}]`  and

`2nd json array`

`[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"}]`

here both the `name` field matches  i,e `"name":"hx inda pvt ltd" == "name":"hx inda pvt ltd"` , therefore i want to `construct`  `3rd json array` like this (`resultant array`)

```
[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"}]
```

here is my sample data

```
var json1 = '[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646"},{"name":"lg inda pvt ltd","mobile":"08063553"},{"name":"sahasra agency","mobile":""}]';

var json2 = '[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"},{"name":"sahasra agency","email":"sah@gmail.com","address":"#444  nagar"}]';


resultant array:

var result = '[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"},{"name":"sahasra agency","mobile":"","email":"sah@gmail.com","address":"#444  nagar"}]';
```

my overall saying is that if `name` field matches then `combine` them as a `resultant` array.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [jQuery.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend), and possibly [JSON parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

First, you need to parse the strings into arrays. Then iterate through the arrays and compare the names.
If they match, extend will clone the objects.

```
var arr1 = JSON.parse(json1);
var arr2 = JSON.parse(json2);

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j< arr2.length; j++){
        if(arr1[i].name === arr2[j].name)
            $.extend(true, arr1[i], arr2[j]);
    }
}
```

If you would like the information in a string, as initially presented, feel free to use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
`var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr1);`

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoq1nqv7/1/)

Comment: my expected result is this   `[{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"},{"name":"sahasra agency","mobile":"","email":"sah@gmail.com","address":"#444  nagar"}]`  but in your case there are `3 results`

Comment: The array contains 3 objects, which (if expanded) is what you expect

Comment: I have edited the jsfiddle with another console.log of the stringified array of objects, using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you. I have taken direct object please use `JSON.parse` to convert your string to an object.**

```js
var json1 = [{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","mobile":"95467646"},{"name":"lg inda pvt ltd","mobile":"08063553"},{"name":"sahasra agency","mobile":""}];

var json2 = [{"name":"hx inda pvt ltd","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":"#141 vr pura"},{"name":"sahasra agency","email":"sah@gmail.com","address":"#444  nagar"}];

var resultObj = [];


for(let i in json1) {
  let name = json1[i].name;
  for(let j in json2) {
    if(json2[j].name === name) {
      var tempData = json2[j];
    
      let newObj = {};
      newObj["name"]    = json1[i].name;
      newObj["mobile"]  = json1[i].mobile;
      newObj["email"]   = tempData.email;
      newObj["address"] = tempData.address;
    
      resultObj.push(newObj);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultObj));
```